# checksum of a hex numbers string

Tags: bash, sum, hex

I have a .txt file in which i got 7 columns of hex numbers. Every number is one byte, so every number is written with 2 characters. I Wanted to sum the first six columns (in hex), compare the last 2 characters (in hex) of the result with the 7th column and if it's not the same delete the row. I am using bash in linux so i think i'll need a pipe of commands to do the job.
A sample of the data is:

de 55 7a ff 41 4e 3b 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..

the sum of the first six numbers (in hex) is 33b and the "checksum" number is 3b, as the last 2 characters of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the entire comparison / check with a single `awk` command, but it may not be pretty.

The tricky part is taking the numbers you have, `de` for instance, and telling `awk` that it's hex and not a string / decimal. We can accomplish this by prefixing it with `0x` and then using `strtonum()`.

After we've converted our numbers to "usable numbers", we can perform the math of adding the first 6 columns and then take a sub-string (the last two characters) of the result and compare it with the 7th column. If they're equal, print that line; if not, ignore it:

```
awk '{
    x = sprintf("%x",
            strtonum("0x"$1)
            + strtonum("0x"$2)
            + strtonum("0x"$3)
            + strtonum("0x"$4)
            + strtonum("0x"$5)
            + strtonum("0x"$6)
     );

     if (substr(x, length(x) -1, length(x)) == $7) {
         print $0
     };
}' input.txt
```

(note: you may have to put the `sprintf()` contents on a single-line to get it to execute properly; I expanded it here for readability)

To output this to a file, you can append `> output.txt` to the end of the above command and it will contain only the lines that matched with all of the ones that didn't effectively "removed".

If you want to overwrite the original, which I would recommend against unless you absolutely don't need it, you can append `> output.txt && mv output.txt input.txt` (it will prompt you to confirm the overwrite).